# Why is My End Bracket an error in unity 2018.14

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a new user to unity and I'm trying to create my first game but in my Game Manager my End Bracket is an error C1513 } expected

Here's my code :

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
    public void Endgame();
    bool gameHasEnded = false;

    public void CompleteLevel ()
    {
       Debug.Log("Level Won");
    }

    public void Endgame()
    {
       if (gameHasEnded = false)
       {
          gameHasEnded = true;
          Invoke("Restart, restartDelay");
          Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
       } 
    }
```

Comment: you have to add another closing bracket (**}**), The reason for the error is that the class is not complete you are missing the **}**. This is what your error says ] expected. read your errors, sir.

Comment: All the bracket problems go away once you align your code properly. Once you do this it becomes clear that there is a curly bracket missing to close your class. I edited your question so the class is properly indented..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a close bracket. Better formatting might help prevent this. Correct your code to:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour{
     public void Endgame();
     bool gameHasEnded = false;

     public void CompleteLevel ()
     {
         Debug.Log("Level Won");
     }



      public void Endgame()
      {
         if (gameHasEnded = false)
         {
             gameHasEnded = true;
             Invoke("Restart, restartDelay");
             Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
         }

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a curly bracket ( **}** ) in the end of the code